# 3D rotation sphere in flash

Tags: flash

How can I receive the 3D rotation spheres like balls in this sample http://www.miniclip.com/games/8-ball-quick-fire-pool/en/

I think its not using a library like papervision3D?

Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

You can make 3D balls by Swift 3D and then export it for Flash...

Comment: I'm don't think that in the sample they do that way

Answer (score 0):

Check out the flash source code at shinedraw on his [3D Spinning/Rotating Globe](http://www.shinedraw.com/3d-illusion/silverlight-vs-flash-3d-spin-rotate-globe/). Source is downloadable on the page. This sample uses Papervision 3D.

I don't know what your example uses though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm don't really think that its papervision. In your sample the flash earth looks little rought